# Cannot find name 'jquery' in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on to use the ng2-datetime. Installed through npm, but when I build the solution, I am getting an error that cannot find name 'jQuery'.

I have added the jQuery through npm and also tried to include the jquery library, but the issue still persists.
Can anyone tell what else to include? I'm using angular 2.2 with typescript and my IDE is VS2015

**app.module.ts**

just added the import statement

```
import { NKDatetimeModule } from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';
```

and under imports

```
@NgModule({
    imports:[NKDatetimeModule ])}
```

Comment: have you included 'jQuery.js' in index.html ?

Comment: Need more information - are you using Angular-cli? Are you using typescript? Where and when do you get the error?

Comment: @anshuVersatile yes I have added     <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

Comment: Need more information - can you post code ?

Comment: @anshuVersatile  I have updated the question

Comment: @zoidy I have updated the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got it working by installing `@types/jquery` from npm.

Comment: And ensure that your `tsconfig` specifies `"types": ["jquery"]`.

Answer (score 94):

3 Steps:

1. Install jQuery. (skip if already installed)

   ```
   npm install jquery --save
   ```
2. Install types for jQuery.

   ```
   npm install @types/jquery --save
   ```
3. Import jQuery in **app.module.ts**.

   ```
   import * as $ from 'jquery';
   ```

Comment: Step #3 does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: Nah, the step #3 IS important or at least it was important for me and it was exactly what was missing! When not including it, my angular CLI would not compile and throw me an error saying "Cannot find name '$'." Here this topic is also being discussed if anyone is interested. A lot of developers seem to have the same problem.

Comment: @AlexRebula This I can confirm. I installed types, still, without step #3 the compiler was missing the dollars :)

Answer (score 10):

after installing jQuery

> npm install jquery --save

and the jQuery TypeScript autocomplete

> npm install @types/jquery --save-dev

now you have to add this reference **"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"** to the **Angular-cli.json**  file at the root of your angular Cli folder *inside* the **Scripts: []** property. after that, jQuery will be available for you as a global variable, Great!

Answer (score 2):

Its because your ***typings*** for jquery is not found, Use the following Command

```js
typings install dt~jquery --save --global
```

If you want to save as a dependency remove "--***global***" flag

Answer (score 0):

For me this method worked:

1. npm install jquery --save
2. npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
3. Adding jquery in angular.cli.json/angular.json, also check the path of jquery.min.js :

“scripts”: [ “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js”,
“../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js”]

Ensure bootstrap dependency is after jquery, if you are using bootstrap.

4. In app.component.ts file:
   declare var $: any;

Answer (score 0):

[Updating typescript@latest also worked](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/43977#issuecomment-841724080)