# What version of jquery angular 4 holds

Tags: angular

I am running into a situation where I need to use jQuery and thought angular 4 might include the same version of jquery as angularJS have a light version of it.

If angular 4 internally have a jquery that what kind of jQuery it have. jQuery lite or full version?

Comment: Angular doesn't include jquery internally. Also, it is discouraged to use codes that include direct DOM access (which jquery does a lot) since it is not very "aot-friendly".

Comment: The often-repeated StackOverflow non-answer: _Why do you think you need jQuery?_ There's a very good chance angular will do what you want, you just have to discover how. Tell us, maybe we can offer a solution.

Comment: I'd like to be able to programmatically disable a component, but I do not have access to that components code (it is nested in an imported component, our application header which has many features). All I have access to is it's class, I'd like to use some kind of class based selector to get a pointer to that view component and disable it. The component I'm trying to disable contains a drop-down, which is the real thing I'm trying to disable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular (2/4) does not include jQuery at all. However angularjs have jQuery light.

Answer (score 4):

Angular does not include jQuery; you must include it manually, by, for example:

`npm install jquery @types/jquery`

This will, at the time of this writing, install `3.2.1`.

Then make sure `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` is included in your build (there are many build workflows so I won't get into the examples).

Then add

```
 declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

after your `import`s and before your `@Component` decorator in the components whose templates use jquery.

Comment: JQueryStatic still not working here, though this is working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994719/cannot-find-name-jquery-in-angular2

Comment: @JuniorM This works in my build. Which _answer_ are you referencing in that link, and how is it "still not working"? Open a new question, perhaps?

Comment: That one with more than 30 votes. Latest versions of Angular (2 and 4) has no jQuery, right? So what have worked for me was `npm install jquery --save`, `npm install @types/jquery --save`, and then `import * as $ from 'jquery'`. But later I figure out that it is recommended to avoid using jquery in Angular and try to manipulate DOM as shown here https://angular.io/guide/user-input. Well, I think we should also avoid DOM manipulation if possible...

Comment: @JuniorM Of course it's not recommended: Angular does everything you need. But some people don't care and just want to use jQuery. This is how. :)