# Issue on how to add jQuery into angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Hi I want to add some jquery code into my angular 2 projet to add input text field dynamically, its work, but the removeTextField doesnt execute when I click on it heres the code:

```
addTextField(){
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + this.counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ this.counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + this.counter +
      '" id="textbox' + this.counter + '" value="" >'+'<span (click)="removeTextField(this.counter)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" style="z-index:33;cursor: pointer">  </span>');
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
this.counter++;

}

 removeTextField(currentTextField){
  alert(currentTextField);
 }
```

any suggestions, please!!!

Comment: Is this code under ```document ready``` function and then you have initialized the controller inside that?

Comment: theres no controller i'm using angular 2..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What version of jquery angular 4 holds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400320/what-version-of-jquery-angular-4-holds)

Comment: this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) might help .check the question with and without typings

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

For example if your input text field is like

```
<input type="text" class="my-input-field">
```

In your controller

```
$(document).click("on", ".my-input-field", ()=>{
   //capture the currentTextField using jquery
   this.removeTextField(currentTextField);
})

   removeTextField(currentTextField){

}
```

**Example**
Its a datatable implemented in angular 2.. The update and delete buttons are rendered on the fly.

**HTML**

```
<table class="datatable table table-striped table-bordered" (click)="onTableClick($event)"></table>
```

**Controller**

```
onTableClick(event){

   if(event.target.className.indexOf('update-row')!= -1){ //will get the class name and check if matches update button class
     this.updateRow($(event.target).attr("data-id"))
   }
   if(event.target.className.indexOf('delete-row')!= -1){ //will get the class name and check if matches delete button class
     this.deleteRow($(event.target).attr("data-id"))
   }
  }
```

Comment: there are text field injected..thats why i'm inject removeTextfield on newTextBoxDiv

Comment: remove (click)="removeTextField" and put class="removeTextField" and follow the code.. and instead of .my-input-field in the code, put removeTextField, it will work

Comment: i have to pass a parameter inside the function..like mine did u get the point i cant use class

Comment: use data-* to pass the parameter. Use .attr() of jquery and pass the parameter.

Comment: I updated the answer...Here i capture the click event in the parent element and get the class where the event happened